# Search cell "address" in row based on last value in row in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, match, formula

I would like to ask for help.

I need to improve my order capacity system.
For each order, I have one row of "1","0" in timeline telling me the beginning & end of production. The order takes some time in production, (=1) means producing, (=0) either in queue or produced.

The question is how to get the reference (index) of last cell with ="1".

example:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   col5   col6   col7   col8
0      0      0      1      1      1      0      0
```

best case results

```
Index (1, 6)
```

I am using lookup formula to find the last "1" value. But I don't know, how to combine it with *=cell("address",...)*
or any other formula
Any ideas?

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjy0dTG-7LwAhVpElkFHVQzAS4QFjACegQIBRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmeta.stackexchange.com%2Fquestions%2F66377%2Fwhat-is-the-xy-problem&usg=AOvVaw1RW8UpIl7QYxoW-PU7zAk9). Why do you need the cell address?

Comment: With Excel365 you can use XMATCH() to get last column number having 1 then use ADDRESS function like `=ADDRESS(1,XMATCH(1,A1:A6,0,-1))`